# When is the correct time to evaluate a ViewBuilder in a SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, viewbuilder

Given a custom content view that accepts a ViewBuilder as it's content, when is the best time to execute the ViewBuilder, in the custom views init or in its body?

```
struct Custom<Content: View>: View {
   init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
      // Option 1
      self.content = content()
      // Option 2
      self.content = content
   }
   var body: some View {
      ...
      // Option 1
      content
      // Option 2
      content()
      ...
   }
}
```

This has been asked before, and the SO answer referenced [this Q&A](https://onmyway133.com/posts/wwdc-swiftui-lounge/#use-viewbuillder) which provides an answer, but it seems somewhat unofficial. Is there any official documentation on this, or an explanation of the pros and cons of each approach.

Comment: That page looks like a copy paste from swiftui lounge, so I would consider it quite official. It also mentions pros of that approach. I think the advantage of opposite approach is that you can use a default struct initializer, instead having your custom one. With one property it won't matter, but if you have a bunch + some bidnings to pass (which you have to then wrap manually), you may be tempted to bypass the "micro-optimization" storing view gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to pass a non-escaping function and evaluate early, if you can.  So, in your example, option 1 and remove `@escaping`. When a closure is passed non-escaping, it can be stored entirely on the stack, which is more efficient than storing it on the heap.

If you look at SwiftUI's built-in views, you'll find that many of them take non-escaping `@ViewBuilder` arguments, which means those views are executing their arguments immediately.

For example, the `content` argument of [`VStack.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/init(alignment:spacing:content:)) isn't `@escaping`. This means `VStack` cannot store `content` in an instance variable. Therefore we can deduce that `VStack.init` executes `content` immediately, and cannot in the future be changed to store it for later execution (because adding `@escaping` is not backward-compatible).

Compare with [`ForEach.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/init(_:id:content:)-82hm4), where the `content` argument is `@escaping`. This means `ForEach` can store `content` in an instance variable to call later, and we expect it to do so if, for example, `ForEach` is used inside `LazyVStack`.